# how to change the CSS Class of the asp label dynamically based on its value

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying certain information about the customer at the admin side and one of the details i am displaying is "EventStatus" . Now **EventStatus** has different values like 'accepted','rejected','pending','in progress' , etc.

Now i am loading this information dynamically from the database.

What i want to do is - to change the css of this label on the basis of the 'value' it is having.

my aspx code is :

```
<tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# Eval("CustomerName") %></td>
                                <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                                <td><%# Eval("EventType") %></td>
                                <td><%# Eval("EventDate", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" CssClass="label label-primary" Text='<%# Eval("EventStatus") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tbody>
```

C# code on Page_Load :

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                EventLogic eventLogic = new EventLogic();

                rptr.DataSource = eventLogic.pendingOrders(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
                rptr.DataBind();
            }
```

I have added this ItemDataBound_Event :

```
protected void rptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Event eventItem = (Event)e.Item.DataItem;
            Label lblStatus = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblStatus ");

            switch (eventItem.EventStatus)
            {
                case "Accepted":
                    lblStatus.CssClass = "label label-primary";
                    break;
                case "Rejected":
                    lblStatus.CssClass = "label label-rejected";
                    break;
                case "Pending":
                    lblStatus.CssClass = "label label-info";
                    break;
                case "In Progress":
                    lblStatus.CssClass = "label label-warning";
                    break;
                case "Completed":
                    lblStatus.CssClass = "label label-success";
                    break;

            }
        } 
    }
```

But i am getting an Error  : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'BusinessLogic.Event'.

Comment: Look at [Repeater.ItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Would be a good place to change CSS class.

Comment: this was a good example, but here they are setting the **text** of the asp:Label by putting an Eval Tag in the Text property.. How would i put the same for a CssClass property of the asp:Label control..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [ItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event rather than relying on `Eval`.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptr_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
             <td><asp:Literal ID="litCustomerName" runat="server" /></td>
             <td><asp:Literal ID="litName" runat="server" /></td>
             <td><asp:Literal ID="litEventType" runat="server" /></td>
             <td><asp:Literal ID="litEventDate" runat="server" /></td>
             <td><asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" CssClass="label label-primary"></asp:Label></td>
          </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Code:

```
protected void rptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var orderItem = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        Literal litCustomerName = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litCustomerName");
        Literal litName = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litName");
        Literal litEventType= (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litEventType");
        Literal litEventDate = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litEventDate");
        Label lblStatus = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblStatus");

        // set the row data e.g.
        litCustomerName.Text = orderItem["CustomerName"].ToString();         

        switch(orderItem["EventStatus"].ToString())
        {
            case "accepted":
               lblStatus.CssClass = "label label-accepted";
               break;
            case "rejected":
               lblStatus.CssClass = "label label-rejected";
               break;

           // etc...
        }
     } 
 }
```

Note: I've made some assumptions about the type that `pendingOrders` is working with, for the purpose of demonstration I've assumed that the type is called `Order`, you'll want to adjust this to suit your needs.

Comment: i am getting an error of  **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'BusinessLogic.Event'. ** Please see my updated question.

Comment: What type does `pendingOrders` return?

Comment: Okay i did that, changed the cast to `DataRowView` and the switch case too... But now i am getting this error : ` Object reference not set to an instance of an object. `

Comment: On which line in particular? Did you update your repeater markup too? The `object reference error` is probably due to the repeater not finding one of the controls.

Comment: The repeater can't see the `lblStatus` control. It looks like you have a space in the `ID` part of `FindControl()` e.g. `(Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblStatus ");` try removing it.

Comment: yes i had a space there.. that worked just as i needed.. !! Thanks for your help @DGibbs :) (Y)